# fullpage.js and content above the fold

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, google-pagespeed

I'm using fullpage.js and everytime I try to move the scripts at the bottom of the page I have never the 100/100 Google PageSpeed Insights. Is there any way to defer or async the codes in order to unblock the contents above the fold?

```
<script>script number one</script>
<script>script number two</script>
<script>script number three</script>
<script>script number four</script>
<script>script number five</script>

<script type="text/javascript" async src="..."></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="..."></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="..."></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="..."></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.thisisfed.com/js/jqu.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.thisisfed.com/js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){$('#fullpage').fullpage({menu:'#mymenu',css3:false,showActiveTooltip:true,continuousVertical:true,scrollOverflow:true,recordHistory:false,easing:'easeInOutCubic',responsive:900,navigation:true,scrollingSpeed:700,normalScrollElements:'.hidden',anchors:['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen','twenty','twentyone','twentytwo','twentythree','twentyfour','twentyfive','twentysix','twentyseven','twentyeight','twentynine','thirty','thirtyone','thirtytwo','thirtythree','thirtyfour','thirtyfive','thirtysix','thirtyseven','thirtyeight','thirtynine','fourty','fourtyone','fourtytwo','fourtythree','fourtyfour','fourtyfive'],navigationTooltips:['( 01 / 45 )','( 02 / 45 )','( 03 / 45 )','( 04 / 45 )','( 05 / 45 )','( 06 / 45 )','( 07 / 45 )','( 08 / 45 )','( 09 / 45 )','( 10 / 45 )','( 11 / 45 )','( 12 / 45 )','( 13 / 45 )','( 14 / 45 )','( 15 / 45 )','( 16 / 45 )','( 17 / 45 )','( 18 / 45 )','( 19 / 45 )','( 20 / 45 )','( 21 / 45 )','( 22 / 45 )','( 23 / 45 )','( 24 / 45 )','( 25 / 45 )','( 26 / 45 )','( 27 / 45 )','( 28 / 45 )','( 29 / 45 )','( 30 / 45 )','( 31 / 45 )','( 32 / 45 )','( 33 / 45 )','( 34 / 45 )','( 35 / 45 )','( 36 / 45 )','( 37 / 45 )','( 38 / 45 )','( 39 / 45 )','( 40 / 45 )','( 41 / 45 )','( 42 / 45 )','( 43 / 45 )','( 44 / 45 )','( 45 / 45 )']});
    });
</script>
</body>
```

The **jqu.js** is the jQuery

Comment: If you care about speed consider merging all scripts (including the internal) into one file, and load this async. This way you have one request, and you can control the order the scripts are loaded. Personally I don't like to use a script from another domain because availability depends on that host (I asume thisisfed.com is not your domain). In your setup you will have a request to your server for every script.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @het.oosten now I'm 97 / 100 and yes that's my domain.